# How to call an Angular $rootScope method from another global function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

Basically, I am trying to call a $rootScope method from the Facebook Javascript SDK. The SDK code is placed directly in my HTML, something like this:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // FB JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
        FB.init({
            appId: '<My App ID>', // FB App ID
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
            version: 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
        });

        // Check whether the user already logged in
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //display user data
                getFbUserData();
            }
        });
    };

    // Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Facebook login with JavaScript SDK
    function fbLogin() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // Get and display the user profile data
                getFbUserData();
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, {
            scope: 'email'
        });
    }

    // Fetch the user profile data from facebook
    function getFbUserData() {
        FB.api('/me', {
                locale: 'en_US',
                fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,name,email,link,gender,locale,picture'
            },
            function(response) {
                **$rootScope.login(response);**
            });
    }

    // Logout from facebook
    function fbLogout() {
        FB.logout(function() {
            console.log('User has logged out.');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Please note that in my getFbUserData method, I am trying to call a rootScope method called login directly from here. However, this does not work as it says that the rootScope object is undefined or whatever. What would be the correct way to do this? I am using Angular1.5.

Thanks!

Comment: Put all that FB code in an angular service

Comment: @charlietfl - Thanks, that solved my issue. Do you want to answer this question so I can vote it up and mark it correct?